# Is there an alternative way of driver.startActivity() Function?

Tags: java, android, appium

I am using Appium 2.2.3, Java JDK 17.05, Appium Java Client 9.0.0, TestNG 7.8.0. I am trying to run the code below and getting java null pointer exception. Trying to find alternative of

```
Activity activity = new Activity("com.androidsample.generalstore",
"com.androidsample.generalstore.MainActivity");
    driver.startActivity(activity);
```

Is there any other alternative way to configure the app package and activity so I can run multiple @Test s in the same class? Thank you!

```
@BeforeMethod (alwaysRun=true)  
public void setActivity() {
    Activity activity = new Activity("com.androidsample.generalstore",
"com.androidsample.generalstore.MainActivity");
    driver.startActivity(activity);
    }
```

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "pageObjects.android.FormPage.setActivity()" because "this.formPage" is null
    at testCases.eCommerce_tc_2.preSetup(eCommerce_tc_2.java:18)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:139)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:69)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:390)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:325)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.runConfigMethods(TestInvoker.java:810)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:577)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:227)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:50)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:957)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:200)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:148)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:848)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:621)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:443)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:437)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:397)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:336)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1280)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1200)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1114)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1082)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the following methods for staring and closing apps without quitting the driver. As per the investegation I did, startActivity() is deprecated for Appium 2.0.0

**activateApp(java.lang.String bundleId)**
Activates the given app if it installed, but not running or if it is running in the background.
Parameters: bundleId - the bundle identifier (or app id) of the app to activate.

**terminateApp(java.lang.String bundleId)**
Terminate the particular application if it is running.
Parameters: bundleId - the bundle identifier (or app id) of the app to be terminated. Returns: true if the app was running before and has been successfully stopped.

reference: https://appium.github.io/java-client/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mobile: startActivity`. The docs can be found here: https://github.com/appium/appium-uiautomator2-driver/blob/master/README.md#mobile-startactivity

```
driver.executeScript("mobile: startActivity", ImmutableMap.of("intent", "appPackage/appActivity"));
```